# sum of the four quartiles

Tags: r, vector, quantile

newbee to R here.

I have a vector

```
c(29,7,1,13,22,28,8,28,25,29,17,22,22,16,2,1,23,6,18,7,22,25,3,15,2,5,22,12,17,24).
```

I need to find the sum of the four quartiles.

```
quantile.v <- quantile(v, probs = seq(0,1, length.out = 4)); #find 4 quantiles 
quantile.v
```

The result shows

```
>        0% 33.33333% 66.66667%      100% 
>   1.00000  10.66667  22.00000  29.00000
```

The result shows the sum of 4 quartiles is between 22-29. 
So I sort the vector saved as sort.v. Then sum of the number from 22-29 in sort.v

```
sort.v <- sort(v)        #sort the vector
sort.v2 <- sort.v[22:29] #display the values from 22-29
sum(sort.v2)             #sum them up
```

The result is not correct. I have no clue what's wrong here. Please help!

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "sum of 4 quintiles is between 22-29"? I'm not sure how calculating the quantiles with `quantile()` has anything to do with summing?

Comment: Or, maybe more precisely, I don't understand what the sum of the values in `v` between 22 and 29 could possibly have to do with the output of the `quantiles()` function.

Comment: For the record, quintiles are fifths (so `seq(0, 1, len=6)`), your `len=4` suggests *tertiles* or *terciles* (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile).

Comment: likewise Im not "sure" what you mean. But perhaps what you actually want is `sum(v[v >= 22])` "sum of the 4th quantile" Maybe??

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(v[v >= quantile.v[3]])`?

Comment: What does the sum of quartiles (or tertiles or quantiles in general) mean, statistically? What's the purpose of this aggregation of an aggregate? Since you're including the extremes (at least `100%`), you are no longer robust to outliers (a common strength/goal of quantiles), so it seems to me like a "statistic with no clear value". (I'm likely missing something.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. 
The question was directly copied and pasted from the question. I don't understand the question meaning either, I was hoping you guys can understand. But thank you for trying.

Anyway, I got a solution from a friend (half manually) though.

```
quantile(v, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.2))
```

Then I got result:
0% -- 1

**20% -- 5.8**

**40% -- 14.2**

**60% -- 22**

**80% -- 24.2**

100% -- 29

The question is ask to sum the numbers in bold (on the right side). I added them manually though.